# Alternative to List.GetRange without exception?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm loading data from database using Entity Framework. I have a ASP MVC controller, that should display 10 elements per page, where page number is parameter passed into the controller:

```
public ActionResult Blog([DefaultValue(0)] int page)
{
    var blogPosts = db.BlogPosts.ToList()
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.PublishTime)
        .ToList()
        .GetRange(page * 10, 10);

    return View(blogPosts);
}
```

Here, the `GetRange(page * 10, 10)`  call can throw exception in multiple cases, e.g. when the list has less than 10 elements or when `page * 10` index is out of bounds.

This can be solved by a lot of bound checking. I'm wondering, is there a more elegant way of solving this? I'm looking for solution that would return 10 elements if possible, otherwise return as much as it can or null/empty list.

For example, list of 27 elements, first and second page (`page == 0 || page == 1`) would return list with 10 elements, third page (`page == 2`) would return 7 elements and fourth page (`page == 3`) would return null/empty list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want to use `.ToList()` before paging anyway, as this will pull in all records and do the filtering in code which will hurt performance.

Just use `.Skip()` and `.Take()`, which will be translated to the proper SQL by Entity Framework:

```
int pageSize = 10;
var blogPosts = db.BlogPosts
                  .OrderByDescending(i => i.PublishTime)
                  .Skip(page * pageSize)
                  .Take(pageSize)
                  .ToList();
```